# R's officer package not recognizing Powerpoint placeholders in master layouts

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

Placeholders in powerpoint master layouts are not being consistently recognized by the officer package in R. In the example below I've attached a [deck of 2 slides](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rtn6UPWosSipgYuBlTCvl8D-Fgi1FXbg/view?usp=sharing), each using a different master and layout. In the "title" layout, the placeholders display readily when layout_properties() is applied, but when I apply layout_properties() to "title and content" the output is 0 rows. This is a problem because in Powerpoint I can clearly see that there are 3 distinct placeholders in this layout.

```
library(officer)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

file_deck <- "stack_demo.pptx"

deck <- read_pptx(file_deck)

layout_summary(deck)

layout_properties(deck, layout = "title", master = "intro") # outputs correctly
layout_properties(deck, layout = "title + content", master = "body") # incorrectly outputs "0 rows"
```

Comment: I think you'd have better chance of solving your problem by asking on the package GitHub page https://github.com/davidgohel/officer/issues

Comment: @ Tung, it was a bug that has been fixed in the developer version of officer on github.